# Qt Creator How to open include file under cursor

Tags: qt-creator

I'm a new at Qt Creator. Maybe this quiestion is a bit silly. How to open include file that is under cursor in Qt Creator editor?
There is nothing appropriate at the context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the focus on the document type function key F4
https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Creator_Keyboard_Shortcuts

In case you need a shortcut 
You should need the FollowSymbolUnderCursor Go To TopMenu->Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard
and search for FollowSymbolUnderCursor, replace shortcut for whatever you want
and directly you will navigate to the include file.

Comment: F4 key is used for quick switching between source / header. Thank you for shortcuts wiki.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to hold Ctrl key and click with left mouse button on the included file.